# Regarding Addition of elements of payload through dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am adding the elements of a payload in Dataweave 1.0 as below :

%var summation =[[]]

summation :sum ((schemaInput map ($.BenefitLimit when $.BenefitLimit !="" otherwise (0 as :number)))) ,

Can anyone help me to replicate the same logic in Dataweave 2.0 ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough conversion without knowing the context.

A few points on the changes:

1. dw 2.0 header
2. fun or var instead of %var - no need for %
3. when/otherwise in dw 2 is now if/else
4. use sum instead of :sum - no need for : anymore with operators and functions

   %dw 2.0

   output application/java

   var data= [ {"BenefitLimit": "10"}, {"BenefitLimit": "20"}]

   fun summation(schemaInput) = sum ((schemaInput map ((if ($.BenefitLimit == "") 0 else $.BenefitLimit as Number))))

[image]
Documentation on migration here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-dataweave

Comment: Hi , The problem is that if the benefitLimit is ="" (blank) in that case summation throws error.how to resolve it